# Error setQuery in FirebaseRecyclerOptions

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I'm struggling with this error. I'm trying to use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and while building the options, I get this error with SetQuery in FirebaseRecyclerOptions. Any clues ? Thank you.

```
    None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
    public open fun setQuery(p0: Query, p1: SnapshotParser<Tuto!>): 
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Tuto!> defined in 
    com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder
    public open fun setQuery(p0: Query, p1: Class<Tuto!>): FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Tuto!> 
    defined in com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder
```

And here is my code:

```
firebaseDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()

val tutosRef = firebaseDB!!.collection("tutos")

val tutoQuery = tutosRef.limitToLast(50);

val options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Tuto>()
        .setQuery(tutoQuery,Tuto::class.java)
        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
        .build()


val adapter = object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Tuto, TutoAdapter>(options) {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TutoAdapter {
        return TutoAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.tuto_holder, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TutoAdapter, position: Int, model: Tuto) {
        holder.bind(model)
    }


}
```

And my Tuto class:

```
class Tuto{
var alias: String? = null
var title: String? = null
var description: String? = null
var owner: String? = null
var date_creation: Timestamp? = null
var steps_list: List<String>? = null
var steps_number: Int? = null

override fun toString(): String {
    val result: String
    result = """
           
           ${date_creation.toString()}
           $description
           $owner
           $steps_number
           $title
           
           """.trimIndent()
    return result
}
}
```

Comment: Suggestion : If you are using kotlin , use data class instead , already serializable and  you wont need to override toString().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase offers two databases, Firestore and Realtime Database.  They are completely different databases with different APIs.  Your code is querying Firestore:

```
firebaseDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val tutosRef = firebaseDB!!.collection("tutos")
```

But you are using Firebase UI for Realtime Database:

```
val options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Tuto>()
        .setQuery(tutoQuery,Tuto::class.java)
        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
        .build()
val adapter = object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Tuto, TutoAdapter>(options) {...}
```

You will need to instead follow the instructions for [Firebase UI for Firestore](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/README.md), which involves using `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck on this one for so long! :)